# Jmeter - I could not find exact streps to generate ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt

Tags: jmeter

I am using jmeter. Tried to search for ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt and could not see anywhere

Also not got right steps to follow to generate the same in http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder

Help me

Thanks
eshavK

Answer (score 0):

They are placed in below folder.

```
JMETER_HOME/bin
```